# Not able to execute shell script in php

Tags: php, shell

I am able to execute the shell script through php via command line terminal. But I am not able to execute the same script(.sh) using php when clicked on HTML button through browser.

Following is my php script(wettyload.php)-

```
<?php
    shell_exec('/var/www/html/wettyload.sh');
?>
```

Following is my shell script(wettyload.sh)-

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/wetty
node app.js -p 8080
```

Following is my html code(url.html)-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form2" method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1/wettyload.php">
            <input type="submit" id="url" name="url" value="Connect terminal">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Maybe your webserver does not have root access?

Comment: Your shell script will be executed under the default web user. Make sure that user has execute permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php
    shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/wettyload.sh');
?>
```

---

**Update:**

You didn't mention `/root/wetty` before, you've a couple of options:

1. Move the `wetty` dir to a location where the webserver user has execute permissions.
2. Set the permission of `/root/wetty` to allow the webserver user to execute (unsafe)

---

**Note:**
Make sure you've `execute` permissions to `wettyload.sh`

Comment: You think web user has any permissions to `/root`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver The OP updated the question in the meanwhile, there was no mention to root before...